# It is said that atoms cannot be created. If so, then how did atoms get created after the Big Bang?

Tags: atoms, astrochemistry

I read somewhere that atoms cannot be created. If this is true, then how did the atoms form after the Big Bang? Also, does this mean that the number of atoms in our universe has remained the same since then? Also, what happens as the universe expands? Does the atoms just scatter or are new atoms being created?

Comment: It looks like your question is rather abot physics and astronomy than chemistry.

Comment: Perhaps what you read is not true.  A simple counterexample would be alpha decay, which turns one atom into two. Of course, fusion turns two atoms into one...

Comment: Simply put atoms are not created or destroyed in chemical reactions, but in nuclear they certainly are.

Comment: Hey, just that there's the tag atoms doesn't mean this is a chemistry question!:D Please take a look at how these concepts are categorized at the reliable sites in the Net. This is astrophysics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about astrophysics more than chemistry. It surely can be dealt with better at physics.SE or astronomy.SE.

Comment: Historically, in chemistry texts it was common for there to be statements like "All the results of chemistry prove that the ultimate atoms of bodies are unchangeable and imperishable...by no natural process can material atoms be either created or destroyed" Textbook of Chemistry by Draper 1846.  So historically the princple that atoms are not created or destroyed has been the foundation of chemistry and the question is relavent to chemistry in that sense, but the details of the answer are nuclear physics and astrophysics.

Comment: @DavePhD, the question title and contents are astrophysics, the concepts are astrophysics, its answer is astrophysics, its parents are astrophysics... :D You be the judge. The almost-a-little-higher-than-trivial fact that chemists at "Dalton"'s age believed the atom to be non-breakable, non-producible and non-destructible doesn't really make it a chemistry Q rather than a physics Q.

Comment: "I have been engaged in experiments which suggest that the atom can be artificially disintegrated. If it is true, it is of far greater importance than a war!" Rutherford, 1917.  The belief prevailed long after Dalton.  I suppose the relavence to chemistry depends upon how important one considers the history of science to science education.

Answer (score 8):

Atoms can be created and destroyed.  For example, in nuclear fusion two or more atoms make one atom.  In nuclear fission, one atom makes two or more atoms.

> how did the atoms form after the Big Bang?

The theory of this process in known as [Big Bang Nucleosynthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis)

[image]

Starting from protons and neutrons, light elements formed.  Later, in stars, nuclei up to iron formed through nuclear fusion.  Nuclei heavier than iron formed from supernovae by the [r-process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-process) and asymptotic branch giant stars by the [s-process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process).

> Also, does this mean that the number of atoms in our universe has remained the same since then?

No.  The number constantly changes due to fusion, fission, supernovae, creation of neutron stars, black holes and possibily [quark stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star).

> Also, what happens as the universe expands? Does the atoms just scatter or are new atoms being created?

Currently, this process does not create or destroy atoms.  However, according to the theory of [accelerating expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_universe), there is a senario referred to as the "[big rip](http://io9.com/5919193/the-big-rip-theory-says-the-universe-could-end-in-tears)" in which all atoms would be destroyed.